# Determine if it is safe to delete a local git repository

Tags: git, version-control, git-status

I very often have have a development clone of a git repository on my laptop, on which I create feature-branches and such to implement features. When I'm half way there working on a feature, but need to work on something else in the same repository, I do a `git stash` and checkout a new branch for that feature.

Of course, `git branch` tells me about all the branches there are. Nevertheless, after a while a local checkout may exist on my laptop, having some feature-branches not pushed or even existent on the remote origin branch. After not working on a project for some time, the checkout may clutter up my workspace, and I may wish to remove it from my laptop.

Moreover, I might also want to know for a repository what new files and changes exist on my laptop, but not in the origin. `git status` tells me this about the current branch checked out, but only partially as it does not say what commits are already on the server and which not. Moreover, it also does not do so for each branch.

Is there a git command that can tell me what new files and changes, and which feature branches are available on my laptop but not on `origin`, such that I can determine whether it is safe or not to remove the git repo from my laptop?

It would be nice if the command would:

- for each local branch state if it also exists on origin, of origin is up to date with and in which other origin branches it has already been merged (very often you merge a feature branch with master and don't push it to origin).
- for each branch state whether there are local changes not committed yet or just stashed.
- other pit culls I should be aware of.

In general I want a 'is it safe to delete this repository knowing what exists on origin' and even better a 'what stuff did I leave unsolved in this repo' command.

Note, I think is can also be useful to know what's on my laptop and not on origin, for the sake of pointers to what should still be cleaned up.

Moving a repo to a backup folder is a no go, this creates a lot of clutter and in the end it still not clear which code is the most up to date with the least bugs.

Something that might work would be a command that shows commits that are exist locally but not on origin, and commits that are in different branches in origin as they are locally. Moreover, a command that shows uncommitted changed for each branch would be nice, i.e. those that ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first (and very good) step is looking at the output of

```
git push origin --all --dry-run
```

That shows which branches *would* be pushed to the remote. If the output is empty (or "up-to-date" or sth.), the local branch(es) can safely be deleted.

Another command of help is

```
git fetch origin
git cherry -v master origin/master
```

It shows the commits common to your local master and origin/master. The ones
prefixed with a `-` sign are already in origin/master, the ones prefixed with
a `+` sign are not, i.e. if all commits shown are prefixed with `-`, it is safe to drop the local branch. If some are  prefixed with `+`, then master and origin/master differ in these commits.

Actually I would stick with `git push origin --all --dry-run` because it is far easier to interpret.

Comment: Hi. I'm executing "git fetch origin" with "git cherry -v master origin/master" and it gives no result. Does anyone know if this is still working in 2022? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece (IIUC) in the above is: what local files would be lost forever if I deleted this repo? (local database files, for instance, ignored by .gitignore).

It appears to me that

```
git clean -nxd
```

answers this question.